# Determine how much a process is using each disk?

Tags: linux, io, top, proc

How do I tell how much load a particular process is contributing to each of several available volumes/mounts? It seems that `dstat` only shows aggregate stats across all processes per disk, and `iotop` only shows aggregates stats across all disks per process.

Comment: It's kinda bad to ask the same question twice.  You might have edited the title of the original note.

Comment: @mdpc I specifically was asking two distinct questions. I can try to make them more clearly distinguished? To other readers, this is what is being referring to: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72027/iotop-but-for-particular-disk.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not track this information.  Solaris on the other hand does, and this information is available via dtrace

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I use iostat to show I/O statistics for individual devices and partitions. For example, in order to monitor a running cpio task with process id 32731 is use the following command:

```
iostat -xd /proc/32731 -p sda,sdb,sdc,sdd 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use htop. It is a better process monitoring tool that top.

Comment: I already use htop. It does not provide per-process per-disk stats.